# RabbitMQ auto clustering | Docker Swarm

Tags: docker-compose, rabbitmq, docker-swarm, rabbitmq-cluster

I'm trying to create a rabbitmq cluster in docker swarm. I have read trough the documentation, and I think I have tried everything but the auto clustering will not work for me: There will be only stand alone nodes created.

You can see my docker-compose v3 file below:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  rabbitmq-01:
    image: bitnami/rabbitmq:3.11
    #user: "1001"
    hostname: rabbitmq-01
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "rabbitmq-diagnostics", "check_running"]
      interval: 60s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_USERNAME=admin
      - RABBITMQ_PASSWORD=admin
      - RABBITMQ_FORCE_BOOT=true
      - RABBITMQ_ERL_COOKIE=$ecure$string
      - RABBITMQ_NODE_NAME=rabbit@rabbitmq-01
      - RABBITMQ_VM_MEMORY_HIGH_WATERMARK=300M
      - RABBITMQ_DISK_FREE_ABSOLUTE_LIMIT=500M
    configs:
      - source: rabbitmq-01
        target: /bitnami/rabbitmq/conf/custom.conf
        uid: "1001"
        gid: "1001"
        mode: 0644
    ports:
      - target: 15672
        published: 15672
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
    networks:
      - rabbitmq
    volumes:
      - rabbitmq-01-data:/bitnami/rabbitmq/mnesia
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.50'
          memory: 300M
        reservations:
          cpus: '0.25'
          memory: 150M
      restart_policy:
        condition: any
        delay: 30s
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 120s
      placement:
        constraints: [node.labels.rabbitmq == 01]

  rabbitmq-02:
    image: bitnami/rabbitmq:3.11
    #user: "1001"
    hostname: rabbitmq-02
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "rabbitmq-diagnostics", "check_running"]
      interval: 60s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_USERNAME=admin
      - RABBITMQ_PASSWORD=admin
      - RABBITMQ_FORCE_BOOT=true
      - RABBITMQ_ERL_COOKIE=$ecure$string
      - RABBITMQ_NODE_NAME=rabbit@rabbitmq-02
      - RABBITMQ_CLUSTER_NODE_NAME=rabbit@rabbitmq-02
      - RABBITMQ_VM_MEMORY_HIGH_WATERMARK=300M
      - RABBITMQ_DISK_FREE_ABSOLUTE_LIMIT=500M
    configs:
      - source: rabbitmq-02
        target: /bitnami/rabbitmq/conf/custom.conf
        uid: "1001"
        gid: "1001"
        mode: 0644
    ports:
      - target: 15672
        published: 15672
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
    networks:
      - rabbitmq
    volumes:
      - rabbitmq-02-data:/bitnami/rabbitmq/mnesia
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.50'
          memory: 300M
        reservations:
          cpus: '0.25'
          memory: 150M
      restart_policy:
        condition: any
        delay: 30s
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 120s
      placement:
        constraints: [node.labels.rabbitmq == 02]

  rabbitmq-03:
    image: bitnami/rabbitmq:3.11
    #user: "1001"
    hostname: rabbitmq-03
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "rabbitmq-diagnostics", "check_running"]
      interval: 60s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_USERNAME=admin
      - RABBITMQ_PASSWORD=admin
      - RABBITMQ_FORCE_BOOT=true
      - RABBITMQ_ERL_COOKIE=$ecure$string
      - RABBITMQ_NODE_NAME=rabbit@rabbitmq-03
      - RABBITMQ_CLUSTER_NODE_NAME=rabbit@rabbitmq-02
      - RABBITMQ_VM_MEMORY_HIGH_WATERMARK=300M
      - RABBITMQ_DISK_FREE_ABSOLUTE_LIMIT=500M
    configs:
      - source: rabbitmq-03
        target: /bitnami/rabbitmq/conf/custom.conf
        uid: "1001"
        gid: "1001"
        mode: 0644
    ports:
      - target: 15672
        published: 15672
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
    networks:
      - rabbitmq
    volumes:
      - rabbitmq-03-data:/bitnami/rabbitmq/mnesia
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.50'
          memory: 300M
        reservations:
          cpus: '0.25'
          memory: 150M
      restart_policy:
        condition: any
        delay: 30s
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 120s
      placement:
        constraints: [node.labels.rabbitmq == 03]

networks:
  rabbitmq:
configs:
  rabbitmq-01:
    file: config/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-01.conf
  rabbitmq-02:
    file: config/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-02.conf
  rabbitmq-03:
    file: config/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-03.conf
volumes:
  rabbitmq-01-data:
  rabbitmq-02-data:
  rabbitmq-03-data:
```

And the rabbitmq config:

```
listeners.tcp.default = 5672
loopback_users.guest = false
cluster_formation.peer_discovery_backend = rabbit_peer_discovery_classic_config
cluster_formation.classic_config.nodes.1 = rabbit@rabbitmq-01
cluster_formation.classic_config.nodes.2 = rabbit@rabbitmq-02
cluster_formation.classic_config.nodes.3 = rabbit@rabbitmq-03
# Don't remove cluster members unknown to the peer discovery backend but log
# warnings.
#
# This setting can only be used if a compatible peer discovery plugin is enabled.
cluster_formation.node_cleanup.only_log_warning = true
# perform the check every 90 seconds
cluster_formation.node_cleanup.interval = 90
# Retry peer discovery operations up to ten times
cluster_formation.discovery_retry_limit = 10
# 500 milliseconds
cluster_formation.discovery_retry_interval = 5000
```

I have tried every possible configuration combination I was able to imagine:

- Attaching the same rabbitmq.conf file under each container
- Attaching different config files to each container.
- Attaching different config file to each container with different configuration included

```
listeners.tcp.default = 5672
loopback_users.guest = false
cluster_formation.peer_discovery_backend = classic_config
cluster_formation.classic_config.nodes.1 = rabbit@rabbitmq-01
#cluster_formation.classic_config.nodes.2 = rabbit@rabbitmq-02
#cluster_formation.classic_config.nodes.3 = rabbit@rabbitmq-03
# Don't remove cluster members unknown to the peer discovery backend but log
# warnings.
#
# This setting can only be used if a compatible peer discovery plugin is enabled.
cluster_formation.node_cleanup.only_log_warning = true
# perform the check every 90 seconds
cluster_formation.node_cleanup.interval = 90
# Retry peer discovery operations up to ten times
cluster_formation.discovery_retry_limit = 10
# 500 milliseconds
cluster_formation.discovery_retry_interval = 5000
```

- Not attaching config file and trying to set up clustering with the bitnami env varibale: RABBITMQ_CLUSTER_NODE_NAME
- All previous scenarios but with the rabbitmq official image...

I was deleting all underlying storage between each retires, to prevent rabbitmq being confused by the previous configuration. With the official rabbitmq image there was some entries in the logs that told me, the system is trying to do peer discovery, but these processes was always timed out, regardless how big threshold was added between retries...
Bitnami containers doesn't log things like that, but the config was readed up, because if I exec into the container I can see the used config in the log, and if I "cat" it, there are my values...

None of these success...
Of course if the standalone nodes are successfully created by the stack deploy (regardless of the configuration attached, every time only stand alone nodes are creating), I can exec into the containers and set up the clustering with rabbitmqcli commands...

How auto clustering should work?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What kind of networks rabbitmq?
Try create networks:

```
docker network create -d overlay --opt encrypted name_network
```

Comment: rabbitmq is an overlay network defined on the end of the conmpose file.